# Selenium WebElement.findElements returns reduced result in scroll pane

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get list of all rows in a table by for using

```
List<WebElement> org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.findElements
```

`findElements` returns me reduced list when table has scrollbar.
Once I scroll the table down to view some more results, `findElements` also returns me more rows.
As a workaround I can scroll to the very bottom of the table before calling `findElements`.

Can you propose a better solution?

I'm using Selenium 2.24.1

Comment: If the full content of the list is loaded asynchronously (i.e. with Ajax), there is no other way than scroll to the bottom. Is that the case?

Comment: the content is loaded by javascript indeed but it is loaded all at once, the whole list is populated at once. What is the problem here?

Comment: Since it doesn't sound like you're using pagination by scrolling, have you tried adding simple waits?  Typically WebDriver waits till document.ready is true after a .click() but if the content is loaded via js, even though it loads all, maybe the content just hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: before calling findElements i'm sending END key stroke to the outer 'scroller' element and this works for me as workaround. As for me, this is bug of findElements implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today. In order to fix it, get your element(the one whom findElements doens't retrieve all) and call click() on it. This way your element will return all children that are in the scrollbar too.